# Windows 2012R2 move folders users, ProgramData, ProgramFiles to the D

Tags: windows, file-management, active-directory

We would like to place the folders `Users`, `ProgramData`, `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` on the D drive for a non AD integrated server. We have already tried many options; however, we have yet to find a viable one.

Is this possible? We’ve read some articles which strongly advise against it.

Options we have tested and the result:

- Symbolic links – This breaks Windows update because of the hard links in Windows.
- Added GPO settings that achieve this on AD environment to registry manually – This works well for the `Users` folder. However the `ProgramData` folder has some hard links in it. – Is this an issue?

From the options we’ve tried, the one with the registry settings seems the most viable. Is this supported? Are there any issues?
If there is another way which is viable and supported please let us know as well.

Background:
We’re a small hosting company which provides cloud services like a online workspace through RDP. Our customers have little to no IT knowledge. We want to create a clear barrier between system data and customer data, without limiting the customer or educating them in the inner workings of the Windows system.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just implement a role based security model so that these system folders cannot be tampered with and give the client a sandbox on the additional drive?

What are you exactly trying to prevent?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

The issue is not in the permissions. This is setup correctly and nobody tampers with folders they shouldn't.

Comment: The issue is in disk space used. We would like to keep the C drive as clean as possible. Further more our commercial model provides the C drive with the system. Customer data is stored on the D drive which is paid for by usage. However there are many customers which leave gigabytes of data in their downloads folder or their and there are applications which fill up the appdata folders. We've experimented with quotas this however does not provide the freedom and insight we want for our customers.